# Databricks query over ODBC errors with Table or view not found: .delta.s3

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to Databricks cluster via ODBC to run some SQL queries from my local python script.

I am following the [Connect Python and pyodbc to Databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/pyodbc.html#using-a-dsn-less-connection)  guide and I am able to get the data from the `samples` table given in the example (`SELECT * FROM samples.nyctaxi.trips LIMIT 10`).

Wheneven I change the query to one reading from my s3 bucket I get this error:

```
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM delta.`s3:/my-bucket/some/path/to/dataset/` limit 10")
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', '[42S02] [Simba][SQLEngine] (31740) Table or view not found: .delta.s3://my-bucket/some/path/to/dataset/ (31740) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

same query works when executed from a Databricks Notebook on the same cluster.

Do I need to set some special properties? Is the ODBC driver having trouble with the backticks (`)?

I am running the exact saem code from the Databricks guide:

```py
import pyodbc
import os

conn = pyodbc.connect(
  "Driver=/Library/simba/spark/lib/libsparkodbc_sb64-universal.dylib;" +
  f"Host={os.getenv('DATABRICKS_HOST')};" +
  "Port=443;" +
  f"HTTPPath={os.getenv('DATABRICKS_HTTP_PATH')};" +
  "SSL=1;" +
  "ThriftTransport=2;" +
  "AuthMech=3;" +
  "UID=token;" +
  f"PWD={os.getenv('DATABRICKS_TOKEN')}",
  autocommit = True
)

# Run a SQL query by using the preceding connection.
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM samples.nyctaxi.trips")

# Print the rows retrieved from the query.
for row in cursor.fetchall():
  print(row)
```

Comment: Did you try with [`UseNativeQuery=1`](https://docs.databricks.com/en/integrations/odbc/capability.html#ansi-sql-92-query-support-in-odbc)?

Comment: Thanks @Kombajnzbożowy! That does it! I think it would make sense to write a proper answer as I think it could help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Databricks ODBC docs](https://docs.databricks.com/en/integrations/odbc/capability.html#ansi-sql-92-query-support-in-odbc) page mentions:

> The ODBC driver accepts SQL queries in ANSI SQL-92 dialect and translates the queries to the Databricks SQL dialect. However, if your application generates Databricks SQL directly or your application uses any non-ANSI SQL-92 standard SQL syntax specific to Databricks, Databricks recommends that you set UseNativeQuery=1 as a connection configuration. With that setting, the driver passes the SQL queries verbatim to Databricks.

Apparently specific constructs like `select from delta.path` can be rewritten (corrupted) using this mechanism. I'm not sure if it's a driver bug or just some ODBC specifics. Anyway, as recommended here, adding `UseNativeQuery=1` to connection string will prevent this issue.